# Touchpad tap working fine, click doesn't work

Tags: 20.04, mouse, touchpad

As suggested by the title, my touchpad click has completely gone but the tap is working just fine. I did see some other topics but they all had the opposite issue.

I really love the click and would love to use it over the tap.

[[image: My laptop specifications]]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try going to setting and enabling tap to click
[image]

if it is already enabled, disable it and enable it again.

Comment: I did that but didn't help. Tap to click works fine but the click doesn't. Do you think there's some issue with the driver? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe....was your click working fine  when you installed ubuntu on your system

Comment: Hi, I have been using Ubuntu for more than a year now, however this issue arose only recently @preIdiot